# Are the dojox-demos currently broken or am I making a mistake?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I assumed that when clicking on one of the links under dojox.gfx from the dojox ["demo and test"-site](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/resources/explore.php) that I can see a demo in my browser (FF 5.0 Javascript enabled).

All of them seem to be broken for me currently (23.07.2011).

E.g for the [bezier-demo](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/gfx/tests/test_bezier.html) all I see is the following text, with a big white area between the two sentences:

> Approximation of an arc with bezier
>
> That's all Folks!

**Do they work for you?
Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the site?**

Comment: I don't see anything at your links - they seem to be broken.

Comment: Right now I can't connect to the links as well, iow I'm currently not even getting the stuff I quoted an hour ago but just getting "Unable to connect"-messages, so perhaps they are currently fixing the issue.

Comment: Not sure if my last comment made this clear, but the links themselves were correct I even still have tabs with the exact links open where I can still see the quote "Approximation of an arc with bezier That's all Folks!".

Comment: They are broken for me too, and seem to have been for a while. Had to go back all the way to 2011-07-18 for a working version. http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/dojo-2011-07-18/dojotoolkit/dojox/gfx/tests/test_bezier.html

Comment: @Frode: Thanks for trying it out and giving a link to an older version that works. If you post it as a reply I would mark it as the answer.

Comment: Heh, I'd feel cheap for getting points for a simple comment, but eh.. I *do* like points :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are broken for me too. I had to go back all the way to 2011-07-18 for a working version: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/dojo-2011-07-18/dojotoolkit/dojox/gfx/tests/test_bezier.html

The Dojo team is currently hard at work making the framework CommonJS compliant for version 1.7. Judging from the error I get on the nightly link, this is related to that.

In summary, no, you are not misunderstanding the purpose of the site. However, since the nightly build is really just a snapshot of the repository last midnight, there isn't a hard guarantee that it will be working like the normal Dojo releases. They don't usually commit changes that breaks it, but it can happen.